# searchContacts() email query: is it broken?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I've been working on a personal Apps Script lately for pulling contact info from a spreadsheet, checking if it exists in my contacts, and adding or modifying the contact based on whether it exists or not. I asked another question recently related to this script.

I've got pretty much the whole thing functional now. However... I keep getting inconsistent results when using the People API method `.searchContacts()`. I've checked the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts), as well as plenty of posts here on stackoverflow, but can't seem to get it working. I'm wondering if it's because I'm trying to query for an email address, since I saw that queries for phone numbers seem to be broken...

I have a function that takes an email address as input, and returns a person object, as follows:

```
function checkEmailExists(email) {
    var personObject = People.People.searchContacts({
      "query": email.toString(),
      "readMask": "emailAddresses,memberships"
    });
  return personObject;
}
```

Since I'm pulling the email address from an object in an array that I've set up, I tried to stringify the email before running the query, just to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Per the documentation, I run this function twice, once with an empty set of double quotes as a "warmup," wait a few seconds, then again with the actual e-mail, as follows:

```
Logger.log('Email to check: ' + contact.email);
var personObjectByEmail = checkEmailExists("");
    Logger
      .log('Run warmup of checking for contact...')
      .log(personObjectByEmail);
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
var personObjectByEmail = checkEmailExists(contact.email);
    Logger
      .log('Check for actual contact e-mail.')
      .log(personObjectByEmail);
// If contact is not found, represented by empty braces "{}", the contact will be added with addToContacts(), a separate function that works as expected and adds the contact to my Google Contacts
```

But in this case, my returned value will more often than not produce two sets of empty brace results, even if the contact *exists* in my contacts already. So I keep getting duplicates whenever I run the script.

| Log Results |
| --- |
| 1:25:23 PM Info Email to check: example@gmail.com |
| 1:25:23 PM Info Check if email exists in contacts... |
| 1:25:23 PM Info Run warmup of checking for contact... |
| 1:25:23 PM Info {} |
| 1:25:28 PM Info Check for actual contact e-mail. |
| 1:25:28 PM Info {} |

I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong, or if it's just an issue with email queries being broken like phone number queries apparently are... I know I can use another method to just pull the whole contact list and search through that myself instead, but I was hoping to use this method to reduce the amount of code I'm having to type out and use on my end.

To clarify: The email I'm searching for is confirmed as already in my Google Contacts. Sometimes I receive an object as the function's output, but sometimes it's empty braces like above.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your showing log. In your showing script, how can I replicate to obtain `Email to check: example@gmail.com`, `Add the above contact.`, and `User added to Contacts: example@gmail.com` using your showing script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sorry that it was a bit unclear -- I just updated my original post and removed the unnecessary part from the log. The "email to check: " is a logged message that prints the contact.email value that will be checked. The other parts occur after the problem so they are not needed for this question. To explain the issue, for any given person in my contacts, when I search by their email, I'm receiving "{}" as the output when entering an empty query or a query with an e-mail address, but not consistently. Sometimes the function will return a person object as expected.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
In your case, can you please share your working code wherein we can replicate your concern.

Comment: Just to add, How are you modifying your contacts, are you using `Undo Changes` ? Because there is a current issue with People API using the `Undo Changes`, read it here: [People API: After Using "Undo Changes", Contacts Returned from People API Are Inconsistent With Google Contacts Website](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287011872)  and this [Google People API: UpdateContact and UpdateGroup are erroneously returning 404s](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/276340498) which might be the cause of your inconsistent result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. So, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal using another approach. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Twilight I provided all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem... so I'm not sure what you're asking for. The rest of the script works fine so I left it out. I can't provide the whole script since it's hundreds of lines long. When I use this code, in isolation, results are inconsistent for me. I tried using the function and other code outside of the script and still got the same issue. So I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your help! I'm not sure why the issue can't be replicated, but I will try your other solution, since I keep having trouble with this method. I want to return the emailAddresses and memberships as part of the person object, however, rather than a true/false value, so I may modify your solution to match what I need. Thank you again!

Comment: @Twilight also just to clarify... my original issue does not involve modifying or adding the contact. The specific problem is that when I try to use `.searchContacts()` with an **email address** as a **query**, it produces inconsistent results -- sometimes it returns a person **object**, confirming that the contact exists, other times it returns **"{}"** even if the contact actually exists. Regardless... I'm not using Undo Changes. I appreciate your help but unfortunately it doesn't apply to my current issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your current issue of `But in this case, my returned value will more often than not produce two sets of empty brace results, even if the contact exists in my contacts already.`, unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. When I tested your showing script with a sample email address, the object of the search email was returned every run.

From this situation, in this case, how about using a workaround using another approach? This workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve all email addresses in your contact as a list.
2. Search the specific email address from the list.

When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function searchEmail_(email) {
  const values = new Set();
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", { personFields: "emailAddresses", fields: "connections.emailAddresses.value", pageSize: 1000, pageToken });
    obj.connections.forEach(({ emailAddresses }) => emailAddresses.forEach(({ value }) => values.add(value)));
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  // If you want to include OtherContacts in the search object, please use the following script.
  // do {
  //   const obj = People.OtherContacts.list({ readMask: "emailAddresses", fields: "otherContacts.emailAddresses.value", pageSize: 1000, pageToken });
  //   obj.otherContacts.forEach(({ emailAddresses }) => emailAddresses.forEach(({ value }) => values.add(value)));
  //   pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  // } while (pageToken);

  return values.has(email);
}

// Please run this function.
function sample() {
  const email = "###"; // Please set your search email address.

  const check = searchEmail_(email);
  if (check) {
    console.log("Email was found.");
  } else {
    console.log("Email was not found.");
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, when the search email address is included in "People.People.Connections.list", true is returned.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm going to modify it and use it if I can't get the `.searchContacts()` method to work properly. Sorry for bothering you one more time, but I just realized I didn't state which Services I have enabled. Currently I'm using AdminDirectory, Sheets, and People. Is that what should be enabled? I'm wondering if there's some permission/authorization I'm missing that's causing the script to not fully function for me, since you're saying it worked for you every time. I isolated my original code completely, and it is now showing "{}" as the result almost every time.

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo Thank you for replying. In your showing script, I think that People API is required to be enabled at Advanced Google services. In my test, I can search the people using an email address with People API. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So, from `even if the contact exists in my contacts already`, as a workaround, I proposed to search an email address by retrieving a list from "Method: people.connections.list".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have People API enabled. I tested further and found that whenever I set a blank query, i.e. `email = ""`, and then execute my function using it, `checkEmailExists(email)`, it seems to not be processing the query properly. If I use a real email for both the warmup and real execution, it works! I'm not sure why, but I do think that your advice to use the method `people.connections.list` will be more reliable, so I've decided to change my script and use that method instead. Thank you again for your advice!

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo Thank you for replying. If this workaround will be useful, I'm glad.